# Ruby - print answer "if own answer (itself)"

Tags: ruby

Ruby question:

Can I shorten the following code:

```
total = Paper.where(available: true).count
puts total if total > 0
```

I imaged something like this, but I don't know if it's possible:

```
puts Paper.where(available: true).count if itself > 0
```

Is there a way to write this idea in one simple line?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not relevant

Comment: What's wrong with two lines?

Comment: @Dima While I would agree the example is a bit contrived, I believe the OP is trying to find out whether the concept is possible in general.

Comment: Don't shorten it. :) Two separate tasks (query, print) are more readable on two separate lines.

Comment: @PaulRichter, you are right. I was wondering if the concept exists. Two lines is OK, no problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (total = Paper.where(available: true).count) > 0 then puts total end
```

Update: with an instance variable you can do

```
puts @total if (@total = Paper.where(available: true).count) > 0
```

Comment: Would you advise that over what the SO has?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I would, to people trying to answer OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @steenslag for the suggestion, but it is just two lines written in one. The ideia is to find an operator (maybe) that could reference to itself. I agree with the others that readability should be clear all times and, in your example, two lines would be more readable than one.

Comment: [itself] (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-itself) is a method, on Object no less. But I can't find a way to make it work in your example. The one question in your post was to write the code in one line.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is perfect in every way. For fun, you could use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) for a one-liner:

```
Paper.where(available: true).count.tap { |total| puts total if total > 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of off the top of my head would be something like this:

```
total = Paper.where(available: true).count; puts total if total > 0
```

Its the exact same thing as your original except its separating the lines by a semi-colon instead of a new line. And its tends to be less readable, so I would generally avoid doing something like that.

As a side note, while I understand what you're trying to do, honestly, reducing your code from 2 lines to 1 is not a big deal. Frankly, its fine the way it is.

Comment: Thank you @paul-richter, thats correct. I want to reduce from 2 lines to 1 line, but keeping a good readability.

Comment: @FernandoShayani I gotcha. I think steenslag's answer above is probably the best, in my opinion.